# Inconsistent Routing on Development and Production - Heroku Prod Env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, routes

I have an odd routing error. On Development mode, all is good and the world is in a happy place. Once I roll out development on Heroku though, I am getting some odd routing errors that do no happen in Dev. I'll choose the simplest/easiest to explain one to display here:

I have search field partial which is everywhere in my 'logged in' session status. I can navigate to other pages ok, use the search - no problem. When I try to resolve my 'Edit User' page, the thing breaks. The following leads me to believe that the problem is with my search field (heroku logs):

```
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/profile/edit" for 216.231.38.147 at 2012-06-06 03:12:39 +0000
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (6.7ms)
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/navbar/_signed_in_menu.html.erb (7.0ms)
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/navbar/_search_form.html.erb (59.1ms)
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (67.7ms)
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 84ms
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]: 
**2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"users/search", :action=>"search", :method=>"get", :class=>"navbar-search pull-right"}):**
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/shared/navbar/_search_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_shared_navbar__search_form_html_erb__1180266451204086_22567500'
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___173307722190207566_23782400'
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3823486473802009434_37056680'
2012-06-06T03:12:39+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `edit'
```

The issue is this line (i think):

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"users/search", :action=>"search", :method=>"get", :class=>"navbar-search pull-right"}):
```

The funny thing is that the controller specified in the error is not the code I have for that partial, this is what is in my partial:

```
<div class = 'navbar-search pull-right'>
 <%= form_tag controller: 'search', action: 'search', method: 'get', class: 'navbar-search pull-right' do %>
  <div class="sign-in-fields-home">
    <%= text_field_tag :search_query, nil, class: 'span4 search-query', placeholder: 'Search' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "submit navbar nav li a", type: 'hidden' %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

here is my routes:

```
Mercado::Application.routes.draw do


  match '/profile' => "users#show", as: :user_root
  match "/profile" => "users#show" #To show singular resources
  match '/search' => 'search#search' #to search resources

  root :to => 'static_pages#home' 

  resources :users do
    member do 
      get :followers, :following
    end
    resources :profilepictures, only: [ :index, :edit ]
  end    
  resources :profilepictures, only: [ :create, :destroy, :update ]
  resources :microposts, only: [ :create, :destroy ]
  resources :relationships, only: [ :create, :destroy ]  

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/signup' => 'users/registrations#new'
    get '/signin' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    delete '/signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get "/profile/edit" => 'users/registrations#edit' #to edit within the 'profile'
  end

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }
```

Here is a snipit (the relevant portion) of my Heroku Run Rake Routes:

```
           user_root        /profile(.:format)                                 users#show
             profile        /profile(.:format)                                 users#show
              search        /search(.:format)                                  search#search
              new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                           users/registrations#new
```

I should mention that I have made custom Devise controllers that override the Gem's controllers. The Edit Page (where this error happens) has forms on that page.

I have tried moving my route commands up and down and restarting heroku

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar problem.